# don't understand getch in python

Tags: python, getch

I'm trying to use getch class in python to read singel charter from user without enter needed, I have no idea what should i do, I copied this:

```
        class _Getch:
        """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
    screen."""
        def __init__(self):
            try:
                self.impl = _GetchWindows()
            except ImportError:
                self.impl = _GetchUnix()

        def __call__(self): return self.impl()


    class _GetchUnix:
        def __init__(self):
            import tty, sys

        def __call__(self):
            import sys, tty, termios
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
                ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch


    class _GetchWindows:
        def __init__(self):
            import msvcrt

        def __call__(self):
            import msvcrt
            return msvcrt.getch()


    getch = _Getch()
```

but I don't know what should I do next...

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not duplicate, I already been in that question...

Comment: Then [edit] to explain what you've tried, what didn't work and what you'd still like to know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want two things, first that I'll be able to recognize if the arrow keys was enterd and second I want to be able to get input of singel charter from the user without needing to press enter, I saw something called getch here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/ but I have no idea how to use it...

Comment: Please see my comment above. If you *"have no idea how to use it"* then do more research, go and find examples of its use on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you explain me how to use getch? I really don't understand what do you want from me

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the post...

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial service. Why not try *actually using it*, call `getch` and see what happens.